# How to make tab bar and tab bar view inside a list view?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I want to make a list, it has three `TabBar` and `TabBarView` inside.
The `TabBarView` is a dynamic `listview.builder`
Is there a way to make it work without setting fixed height for the list.
Like in the picture instead of `#Header`, it's a `TabBar`, and images are `TabBarView`

[image: Tab bar instead of Header and TabBarView instead of images]

Answer (score 1):

My preferred method is to set the hight to equal AnyList.Length multiplied by the height of the widget inside the list.
For example, if the ListView.Builder is used to create a list of containers with height 200. You can set the height to: AnyList.length * 200

You can also use IntrinsicHeight widget, but Flutter documentation about this widget states that "This class is relatively expensive and you should avoid using it where possible."